# Finding a Combination (Box) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations

I am trying to find whether a set of numbers are contained in another set of numbers.

```
ID NumberSet Result  
-- --------- ------
1  1457      5741
2  4187      7148
3  6324      1345
```

So for this dataset I would return ID 1 & 2. All the numbers from the NumberSet must be contained within the Result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually isn't that hard.  Just look for the reverse . . . is there a case where a number from `NumberSet` is not in `Result`?

For the first row, you could manually create a `like` expression for finding a result that has a character other than "1457":

```
where Result like '%[^1457]%'
```

What you want is:

```
where Result not like '%[^1457]%'
```

Now, let's generalize:

```
where Result not like '%[^'+NumberSet+']%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems not easy but you can look into this blog http://wikiprogrammer.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/find-out-anagram-using-sql/